# python regex: string with maximum one whitespace

Tags: python, regex

Hello I would like to know how to create a regex pattern with a sting which might contain maximum one white space. More specificly:

```
s = "a    b d d  c"
pattern = "(?P<a>.*) +(?P<b>.*) +(?P<c>.*)"
print(re.match(pattern, s).groupdict())
```

returns:

```
{'a': 'a    b d d', 'b': '', 'c': 'c'}
```

I would like to have:

```
{'a': 'a', 'b': 'b d d', 'c': 'c'}
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option could be to use zip and a dict and generate the characters based on the length of the matches.

You can get the matches which contain at max one whitespace using a repeating pattern matching a non whitespace char `\S` and repeat 0+ times a space followed by a non whitespace char:

```
\S(?: \S)*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vHZ09k/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/h3uiky)

For example:

```
import re
a=97
regex = r"\S(?: \S)*"
test_str = "a    b d d  c"
matches = re.findall(regex, test_str)
chars = list(map(chr, range(a, a+len(matches))))
print(dict(zip(chars, matches)))
```

Result

```
{'a': 'a', 'b': 'b d d', 'c': 'c'}
```

Answer (score 3):

With the help of *The fourth birds* answer I managed to do it in a way I imagened it to be:

```
import re
s = "a    b d d  c"
pattern = "(?P<a>\S(?: \S)*) +(?P<b>\S(?: \S)*) +(?P<c>\S(?: \S)*)"
print(re.match(pattern, s).groupdict())
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you just want to split your string with 2 or more spaces. You can do it this way:

```
s = "a    b d d  c"
re.split(r' {2,}', s)
```

will return you:

`['a', 'b d d', 'c']`

Answer (score 2):

It's probably easier to use [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split), since the delimiter is known (2 or more spaces), but the patterns in-between are not. I'm sure someone better at regex than myself can work out the look-aheads, but by splitting on `\s{2,}`, you can greatly simplify the problem.

You can make your dictionary of named groups like so:

```py
import re
s = "a    b d d  c"

x = dict(zip('abc', re.split('\s{2,}', s)))

x
{'a': 'a', 'b': 'b d d', 'c': 'c'}
```

Where the first arg in `zip` is the named groups. To extend this to more general names:

```py
groups = ['group_1', 'another group', 'third_group']
x = dict(zip(groups, re.split('\s{2,}', s)))

{'group_1': 'a', 'another group': 'b d d', 'third_group': 'c'}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found an other solution I even like better:

```
import re
s = "a    b dll d  c"
pattern = "(?P<a>(\S*[\t]?)*) +(?P<b>(\S*[\t ]?)*) +(?P<c>(\S*[\t ]?)*)"
print(re.match(pattern, s).groupdict())
```

here it's even possible to have more than one letter.